# Why hasattr return a wrong result?

Tags: python

Below is my test code:

```
import functools


class LazyLoader(object):

    def __init__(self, klass, *args, **kwargs):
        self.klass = klass
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.instance = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return functools.partial(self.__run_method, name)

    def __run_method(self, __name, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = self.klass(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return getattr(self.instance, __name)(*args, **kwargs)


class SchedulerReportClient(object):
    def method(self):
        print 'method called'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print '__getattr__ called'
        return functools.partial(self.__run_method, name)

    def __run_method(self, __name, *args, **kwargs):
        print '__run_method called'
        return getattr(self, __name)(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = SchedulerReportClient()
    entity = LazyLoader(a)

    print hasattr(entity, 'obj_to_primitive')
    print(callable(entity.obj_to_primitive))
    print entity.__class__.__name__
    if hasattr(entity, 'obj_to_primitive') and callable(entity.obj_to_primitive):
        entity.obj_to_primitive()
```

And the outouts are:

```
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
LazyLoader
  File "C:/Users/chen/PycharmProjects/pytest/main", line 42, in <module>
    entity.obj_to_primitive()
  File "C:/Users/chen/PycharmProjects/pytest/main", line 17, in __run_method
    self.instance = self.klass(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'SchedulerReportClient' object is not callable
```

The code is mostly in openstack nova, I copied some.

There isn't a `obj_to_primitive` method in class `SchedulerReportClient`, why hasattr and callable function return true?

CentOS7.4 with Python2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin function [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) is implemented by calling [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and checking if it raises an exception or not. This is stated in the doc.

> The result is `True` if the string is the name of one of the object’s
>   attributes, `False` if not. (This is implemented by calling
>   getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an exception or
>   not.)

In this case you defined the `LazyLoader.__getattr__` method which returns a partially evaluated method `LazyLoader.__run_method` regardless of the value of the argument `name`.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
        return functools.partial(self.__run_method, name)
```

As a reminder, the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method is called when an attribute was not found by the usual means.

So when you get `entity.obj_to_primitive`, what is returned is `functools.partial(entity.__run_method, 'obj_to_primitive')`.